# How to send data between two phones using NFC in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, nfc

I am building a flutter where an app transfers user details from one phone to another. Initially I built this using a qr code scanner and generator setup.

Now I am trying to pass the data between the devices using NFC.

Could someone tell me how to send an NFC message from a device, and how to accept this message from another device?

I did read through [github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader](https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader), and I understood how to read NFC data, but how can we send NFC data from a device?

Comment: Why don't you google "flutter nfc", right away I found this: https://github.com/matteocrippa/flutter-nfc-reader

Comment: yes mate. that shows me how to read nfc data. but what I wanted to know is,how to send nfc data from a device,so that I can recieve it from the other device.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: yeah if someone found something i'm looking for the same thing!

Comment: same problem here

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I've encountered it and if someone is still searching - [flutter_nfc_kit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit).

> Yet another plugin to provide NFC functionality on Android and iOS.
>
> This plugin's functionalities include:
>
> read metadata and **read & write NDEF records** of tags / cards complying with:
>
> ISO 14443 Type A & Type B (NFC-A / NFC-B / MIFARE Classic / MIFARE Plus / > MIFARE Ultralight / MIFARE DESFire)
>
> ISO 18092 (NFC-F / FeliCa)
>
> ISO 15963 (NFC-V)
>
> transceive commands with tags / cards complying with:
>
> ISO 7816 Smart Cards (layer 4, in APDUs)
>
> other device-supported technologies (layer 3, in raw commands, Android only)
>
> Note that due to API limitations not all operations are supported on both platforms.
>
> This library uses ndef for NDEF record encoding & decoding.

Note: NDEF (NFC Data Exchange Format) is a light-weight binary format, used to encapsulate typed data. It is specified by the NFC Forum, for transmission and storage with NFC, however it is transport agnostic. (source: [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord#:%7E:text=An%20NDEF%20Record%20contains%20typed,chunked%20(partial)%20NDEF%20Records.))